# Unable to get form post

Tags: php, html

I have this simple form which shows a pop up calendar when clicked on

```
<form action = "test2.php" method = "post" onsubmit="jValidate(this);">
<input type="text" name="inputField" size="12" id="inputField"/>
</form>
```

Mentioned below are my `test2.php` codes

```
<?php
$d = $_POST["inputField"];
echo($d);
?>
```

However all I am getting is a blank screen.

Comment: There is nothing mentioned below.

Comment: @David: Fixed formatting

Comment: missing `javascript` code? Post it all, there's room, am sure ;-)

Comment: [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/)

Comment: my calendar is popping out normally but im still unable to send it over successfully

Comment: can you confirm inputField is being set before the submit of that form?

Comment: after i click on the calendar my specific date, the text field is immediately filled with the exact date. Sorry is that what you mean by being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines on top of your page and you *should* see errros/problems instead of blank page (fatal error):

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// etc
$d = $_POST["inputField"];
echo($d);
```

---

## Update

This should put your notice message away:

```
if (isset($_POST["inputField"]))
{
  $d = $_POST["inputField"];
  echo($d);
}
```

Comment: Ok this is what i got after i used your error reporting. Notice: Undefined index: inputField in /var/www/html/test2.php on line 13

Comment: Ok sure got it. Thanks Blaster. Ok now that i know that it is not set. May i check with you how do i set it? is my form syntax wrong?

Comment: @KennethLiow: When you submit form with a value, it is set automatically :) Just use the code I posted in my update.

Comment: For my entire form, i have files and other types being submitted. This is my full form syntax. Please advice. <form action = "test2.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="jValidate(this);">

Comment: @KennethLiow: Yep that's fine.

Comment: Ok, when i remove my id="inputField", im able to get what i need however my calendar is gone. Would appreciate your help blaster

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but sometime we skip the obvious: Should your form look like:

```
<form action = "test2.php" method = "post" onsubmit="jValidate(this);">
<input type="text" name="inputField" size="12" id="inputField" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post It!" />
</form>
```

And maybe you could do with PHP what @Blaster said.

Comment: Oh, ok. Since I haven't seen it in the post I thought you forgot. You know, sometimes the easiest is the easiest to forget.